# Rails scope created within month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date

I've got some issues with writing my model scope. I want to filter my model objects based on a month in which they are published, i.e model BlogPost :

```
scope :published_in_month, ->(date) { where(published_date: date.at_beginning_of_month..date.at_end_of_month) }
```

So this is my controller method :

```
def list_by_month
    @date = Time.parse("#{params[:year]}/#{params[:month]}")
    puts "DATE IS #{@date}"
    @posts = BlogPost.published_in_month(@date).page(params[:page]).per(10)
    render :index
  end
```

So date printed out I see is :

```
DATE IS 2013-12-01 00:00:00 +0100
```

But in my log and it the page I see post(s) from wrong month, this is a entry log :

```
SELECT "blog_posts".* FROM "blog_posts" WHERE ("blog_posts"."published_date" BETWEEN '2013-11-30 23:00:00.000000' AND '2013-12-31 22:59:59.999999') LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Where is this `2013-11-30` coming from when my input date is `2013-12-01`, and how can I rewrite my scope if I made mistake with it to produce incorrect query

Comment: it looks like a time-zone issue - your day ends at 23:00 the previous day instead of in 00:00.

Comment: Synchronize the timezone in your ruby machine with the timezone in your db machine

Comment: It looks to me like your query does what you want.  Assuming your DB is storing timestamps in UTC, but ActiveRecord is configured to use UTC + 1, then that query is exactly what you want.  To be sure, try creating a new record and see what was actually written to the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is better to use SQL methods to determine the month of each record:

```
scope :published_in_month, ->(date) { where("MONTH(created_at) = ?", date.month) }
```

Postgresql version:

```
scope :published_in_month, ->(date) { where("DATE_PART('month', timestamp created_at) = ?", date.month) }
```

(not tested)

Comment: PGError: ERROR:  function month(date) does not exist

Comment: Ah, you did not mention postgresql. See updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, I believe @MarceloBarreto's version would be faster unless you have an index on `DATE_PART('month', created_at)`.

Answer (score 8):

This could help:

```
scope :from_month, -> { where(created_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_month..DateTime.now.end_of_month) }
```