# Wrong number of Arguments (0 for 1) Error using Rails Scope to find all in current month

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, named-scope

I am new to scopes and when creating this found what I thought would work here [Rails scope created within month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245438/rails-scope-created-within-month).  However, my code below, gives wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) and I am unsure why. I appreciate any help offered on the matter.
The scope giving the issue is below.

```
scope :contract_out,  -> (date) { where("DATE_PART('month', contract_out_date) = ?", date.month) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the record within the current month use the following scope:

```
scope :contract_out, where("contract_out_date >= ? AND contract_out_date < ?", Date.today.beginning_of_month, Date.today.end_of_month)
```

To work for any month not only current, scope will be modified to accept 1 attribute:

```
scope :contract_out, ->(date) {where("contract_out_date >= ? AND contract_out_date < ?", date.beginning_of_month, date.end_of_month)}
```

Comment: that did it thanks a bunch mohamed-stark!  just needs to be made callable and good to go!

Comment: Thanks, i extended the answer to work for any date, check it at the second scope.